# Error add txt for domain:_acme-challenge when using acme.sh to renew certificate

Tags: tls

When I am using this command to auto renew my ssl certificate(acme.sh version is 3.0.0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export Ali_Key="123456"
export Ali_Secret="123456"
/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue --dns dns_ali  \
-d poemhub.top -d *.poemhub.top -k ec-256 --debug
```

shows this error:

```
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] url='https://alidns.aliyuncs.com/?AccessKeyId=balabalabala&Action=DescribeDomainRecords&DomainName=top&Format=json&SignatureMethod=HMAC-SHA1&SignatureNonce=1626494117866446458&SignatureVersion=1.0&Timestamp=2021-07-17T03%3A55%3A17Z&Version=2015-01-09&Signature=vubqv06KBvc3JbwlmPT4EU6JI4c%3D'
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] timeout=
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] _CURL='curl --silent --dump-header /root/.acme.sh/http.header  -L  -g '
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] ret='0'
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] Error add txt for domain:_acme-challenge.poemhub.top
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] _on_issue_err
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] Please add '--debug' or '--log' to check more details.
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] See: https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/How-to-debug-acme.sh
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] url='https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/chall/h7Bpd0Klqlk4jmb71f5jjg'
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] payload='{}'
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] POST
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] _post_url='https://acme.zerossl.com/v2/DV90/chall/h7Bpd0Klqlk4jmb71f5jjg'
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:19 CST 2021] _CURL='curl --silent --dump-header /root/.acme.sh/http.header  -L  -g '
[Sat Jul 17 11:55:20 CST 2021] _ret='0'
```

I could not know any error reason from the log output, why give message `Error add txt for domain:_acme-challenge.poemhub.top`? what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Which part of the "Please add '--debug' or '--log' to check more details. See: https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh/wiki/How-to-debug-acme.sh" is unclear?

Comment: I already add --debug@EsaJokinen

Comment: I presume this has been fixed? Usually a CA requires you to show that you control a domain by replying to a specific request. I presume that the script tries to make sure that such a request can be posted.